# R Shiny - add table value hyperlinks pointing to different pdf files on a server

Tags: r, shiny, server, hyperlink

How do I link a table value in Shiny to a pdf file on a server? My code currently looks like this:

```
 output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
        df_mod %>% 
            filter(
                Sample== input$selectSample,
                Year == input$selectYear) %>%
            mutate(
                pdf_name2 = "<a href='testpdf.pdf' target='blank' >MyFile</a>",
                #works but in shiny www folder
                pdf_name2b = "<a href='////server297/doc_source/1334362.pdf' target='blank' >MyFile</a>", #does not works
                pdf_name2c = "<a href='//server297/doc_source/1334362.pdf' target='blank' >MyFile</a>" # does not work
            ),
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        escape = FALSE
    )
```

the `href` to `pdf_name2` works; the file is contained within a www folder of the Shiny app. However pdf_name2b and 2c are not working - I can't seem to link to the server location through the browser (Chrome). I have 30,000 files to link to, so I don't think moving them into the Shiny www folder is an option.

**UPDATE:**

using addResourcePath made it work locally. Once I try to publish I get the error below.
Error message upon publishing to shiny server:

```
2021/02/22 16:02:35.620720970 Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
2021/02/22 16:02:35.620750130   Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'pdf'; `directoryPath` = '//server297/doc_source/'
2021/02/22 16:02:35.620817587 Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2021/02/22 16:02:35.620828810 Execution halted
```

Comment: Try single forward slash: `pdf_name2c = "<a href='/server297/doc_source/1334362.pdf'...`, assuming `/server297/doc_source/` is the full path to your file location.

Comment: @YBS: if I do that I land on a page that simply says "Not Found". With `<a href='\\\\ausydap297/doc_source/NAR_Pub_SEDAR/SEDAR1/1997/1997_01/1334362.pdf' target='blank' >PDF</a>` i get a hyperlink that does nothing. Yet, if I right click and select "Copy link address" and paste into my browser address path it does open the file. That works but wish it would do so by just clicking on the link.

Comment: Answer by @HubertL should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your app to serve files that are outside its `www` folder, you have to declare their folder with `addResourcePath()`:

```r
addResourcePath('pdf', '//server297/doc_source')
```

Then you use the defined prefix as the file's folder:

```r
pdf_name2b = "<a href='pdf/1334362.pdf' target='blank' >MyFile</a>"
```

Comment: see updated comment in the OP. That helped locally but not once I tried to publish. Might it be a package issue on the server end?

Comment: Your path would need to work also on the server